# How do I find the Address Space to which the Subnet belongs using C# in .Net 4/4.5 using CIDR

Tags: c#, ip-address

I have a list of Network Configurations with the list of Address Spaces and List of Subnets. I need to find out the Address Space to which the Subnet belongs. The subnet has its own range of IPAddresses in CIDR format. 
Here is the pseudo code on how I see it working.

```
    List<string> AddressSpaces = new List<string>()
                                            {
                                                "10.1.1.9/27",
                                                "10.0.0.0/8",
                                                "10.100.1.0/20",
                                                "10.200.2.0/20"
                                            };
    List<string> Subnets = new List<string>()
                                    {
                                        "10.1.1.0/27",
                                        "10.0.0.0/11",
                                        "10.100.0.0/23",
                                        "10.100.2.0/23",
                                        "10.200.0.0/23",
                                        "10.200.2.0/23",
                                    };
    private void MapSubnet2AddressSpace()
    {

        foreach(var Subnet in Subnets)
        {
            findAddressSpace(); // how to fetch the respective address space from AddressSpaces 
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Ron: Thanks for the inputs. May be I did not put it correctly, The requirement is to identify the address space  that contains the subnet.

Comment: It's the same algorithm, you just use the mask from the address space instead of the subnet. Given two IP addresses, and using a common mask, are they equal when masked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mask the address space and the subnet with the mask for the address space, if they are equal, it is a match. IPv4 addresses and masks are both 32-bit unsigned integers. If `subnet AND subnet mask` equals `address space AND subnet mask`, then the address space is in the subnet.

You need to be careful that the address space mask length is smaller than or equal to the subnet mask length. For instance, the last three address spaces are not in any subnet. In fact, some subnets are in the address space. For instance, the address space `10.0.0.0/8` doesn't fit in any of the subnets, but all the subnets fit in that address space.